# .Net6 Upgrade with OData v8, Broken DI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, odata

I have a WEB API running on.Net5 for a while with the OData package.

Recently I've started to undertake the upgrade for .Net6 work but OData compatibility is broken at first. I needed to upgrade the OData package as well from v7 to v8.

After the upgrade first, my package references were broken so I've changed them from;

```
"using Microsoft.AspNet.OData;"
```

to

```
"using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData;"
```

Now that resolved many of the errors, but coming back to my OData Config, my

```
services.AddOData();
```

has started to throw the error of **"IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddOData' and the best extension method overload 'ODataMvcBuilderExtensions.AddOData(IMvcBuilder)' requires a receiver of type 'IMvcBuilder'"**

After some research, I've changed that to AddControllers first **"services.AddControllers().AddOData();"** and now my config file is like this;

```
public static void SetupOData(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // OData Support
        //services.AddOData();
        services.AddControllers().AddOData();

        // In order to make swagger work with OData
        services.AddMvcCore(options =>
        {
            foreach (OutputFormatter outputFormatter in options.OutputFormatters.OfType<OutputFormatter>().Where(x => x.SupportedMediaTypes.Count == 0))
            {
                outputFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/prs.odatatestxx-odata"));
            }

            foreach (InputFormatter inputFormatter in options.InputFormatters.OfType<InputFormatter>().Where(x => x.SupportedMediaTypes.Count == 0))
            {
                inputFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/prs.odatatestxx-odata"));
            }
        });
    }
```

However after adding Config to the Startup with

```
// OData 
services.SetupOData();
```

and

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpointRouteBuilder =>
        {
            endpointRouteBuilder.MapControllers();

            // OData configuration
            endpointRouteBuilder.EnableDependencyInjection();
            endpointRouteBuilder.Filter().Select().Count().OrderBy();
        });
```

I am getting error on **EnableDependencyInjection()** "'IEndpointRouteBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'EnableDependencyInjection' and no accessible extension method 'EnableDependencyInjection' accepting a first argument of type 'IEndpointRouteBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

So my OData usage is taking the non-EDM route and tried to implement that as simple as possible. But now after the upgrade, I am completely confused and or blinded right now. Can you help me get through this?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this, @ukgaudram?

Comment: yep changing the Odata Config to AddOData after AddMvcCore (options => .... .AddOData() )worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

So an update;

Changing the OData config worked for me;

Instead of adding Odata first;

```
services.AddOData();
```

I pulled it inside the MvcCore;

```
services.AddMvcCore(options =>
{
    foreach (OutputFormatter outputFormat ......."odatatestxx-odata"));
    }
}).AddOData();
```

And then instead of using DI on endpointRouteBuilder, just kept MapControllers as;

```
endpointRouteBuilder.MapControllers();
```